# Postgres json column with versions, return the oldest one

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the following table:

```sql
create table subscriptions (id int, data jsonb);
```

filled with the following data:

```sql
insert into subscriptions (id, data) 
values 
  (1, '{"versions": {"10.2.3": 3, "9.2.3": 4, "12.2.3": 5, "1.2.3": 5}}'),
  (2, '{"versions": {"0.2.3": 3, "2.2.3": 4, "3.2.3": 5}}');
```

And I am trying to write a query that will result in:

```
 -----------------
| id | minVersion |
 -----------------
| 1  | 1.2.3      |
| 2  | 0.2.3      |
 -----------------
```

What I have tried:

```
select
      (string_to_array(jsonb_object_keys((data->'versions')::jsonb), '.'))[1] as total_prices
from subscriptions;
```

(does not work but I think those methods will be useful here)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(data->'versions')::jsonb` can be simplified to `(data->'versions')` there is no need to cast a `jsonb` value to `jsonb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a function that extracts the version keys and sorts them to pick the smallest.

```
create or replace function smallest_version(p_version jsonb)
  returns text
as
$$
  select version
  from jsonb_each_text(p_version) as x(version, num)
  order by string_to_array(x.version, '.')::int[]
  limit 1
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

The above will only work if there are no versions like `1.2.3-beta` or other non-numeric characters in your version number.

Then use it like this:

```
select smallest_version(data->'versions')
from subscriptions;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/4d2nqEZQ)

Comment: Thanks! Works nice